# Android: not able to play video using videoview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-videoview

Please find below xml

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Java Code:

```
  String url = "android.resource://com.example.androidtutorial/" + R.raw.instructions;
  videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
  videoView.start();
```

Error is shown in Logcat:

```
2019-10-20 10:51:16.708 5063-5063/? E/androidtutoria: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2019-10-20 10:51:22.825 5063-5080/com.example.androidtutorial E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
2019-10-20 10:51:23.178 5063-5063/com.example.androidtutorial E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

I saw many samples on the internet that uses the same code, but in my case, it is not working.

Comment: have look to this link : [Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58394387/7138532)

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to user a WebView instead of video view.

that will work better.

But for your answer

1.check your connection

2.check your permissions

3.check Url that you build with Debug

4.put start method in try catch

Now its seems issue in this line:

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
```

uri means a file path in your device not a url, check it and try again.

u can update me in comments

Edited:
use this method:

```
public Uri getRawUri(String filename) {
    return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + 
File.pathSeparator + File.separator + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + 
filename);
}
```

next solution: use `Uri.fromFile` instead of `Uri.parse`

And

Use this 2 methods:

```
video.setVideoURI(URI);
video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
video.requestFocus();
video.start();
```

Try this in your `onCreate()` method:

```
Uri URI = getRawUri(instructions);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(video)

video.setVideoURI(URI);
video.setMediaController(mediaController);
video.requestFocus();
video.start();
```

Comment: It's a local video, inside the raw folder.

Comment: are you check all the steps that is said?

Comment: Please try at your end then only post these answers, because I already mentioned in my question I tried other samples which are available.

Comment: please complete answer.

Comment: what do u mean? its a completed answer, just try it in your code...

Comment: What is URI in line  "video.setVideoURI(URI);" if you change to Uri.fromFile this will give you a compile-time error. Please post complete java file

Comment: do you want it?

Comment: .mp4   use format in file name like instructions.mp4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201166/discussion-between-jitsm555-and-alireza-daryani).