# App force close while running in using android studio

Tags: android

I am facing **app force close** while running it in the emulator
and when I debug it, those error occurs

> Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

> E/FirebaseInstanceId: binding to the service failed

How can I solve them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unknown bits set in runtime\_flags: 0x8000" warning in Logcat on Android Q emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916587/unknown-bits-set-in-runtime-flags-0x8000-warning-in-logcat-on-android-q-emula)

Answer (score 0):

When you debug your app it stays on the same thread for a long time n it confuses the android system as the App isn't responding, so it pops-up with `app force close` dialog.

Just simply select `wait` n let the dialog disappear. You cant stop the android system by showing `not responding` dialog.